# Firebase push notifications not showing up while app is in background (Emulator)

Tags: android, firebase-notifications

I send firebase push notification to a singe android device from the firebase console. This works well while the app is running in the foreground. I receive the event and onMessageReceived() is called. 
When the app is in the background I'm expecting to see an notification entry to show up in the system notification tray of the emulator. Instead I'm getting the error below and no notification is popping up on the device. My messages are very simple just the message text and the FCM token.

Update:
It seems to be a emulator issue because on a real device it is working.

> com.google.android.gms.persistent D/GCM: Error whitelisting app for waking in doze
>                                                                         java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at ott.a(SourceFile:49473)
>                                                                             at ott.c(SourceFile:1366)
>                                                                             at otn.b(SourceFile:638)
>                                                                             at ahge.a(SourceFile:998)
>                                                                             at ahgf.run(SourceFile:1070)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Calling app  is not on whitelist
>                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
>                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
>                                                                             at android.app.usage.IUsageStatsManager$Stub$Proxy.whitelistAppTemporarily(IUsageStatsManager.java:293)
>                                                                             at android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager.whitelistAppTemporarily(UsageStatsManager.java:266)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at ott.a(SourceFile:49473) 
>                                                                             at ott.c(SourceFile:1366) 
>                                                                             at otn.b(SourceFile:638) 
>                                                                             at ahge.a(SourceFile:998) 
>                                                                             at ahgf.run(SourceFile:1070) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Answer (score 2):

Should use GCM high-priority messages to wake the app and access the network.
Example of High priority GCM message:-

```
{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "priority" : "high",
   "notification" : {
    "body" : "This week’s edition is now available.",
    "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
    "icon" : "new",
  },
  "data" : {
    "volume" : "3.21.15",
    "contents" : "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
  }
}
```

See the "priority" key has value "high", this will awake the device and gcm message will be delivered instantly and it wont crash.

Check this out for more information 
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#whitelisting-cases

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12864053)

Comment: I have now written an example which directly answers the question. Hope now it is no more a low quality answer

Comment: The messages have a high priority. It seem to be a emulator issue. On a real device it is working.

Comment: While useful, this is not an answer to the question:  *high* will make it show up *faster*, or with a more consistent speed, but does not explain a message that *never* shows up.  Also, only do this if necessary, due to extra **battery drain**. [Cloud messaging concepts](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options), section "Setting the priority of a message".  Also, following the link you gave, the better answer is to use **FCM high-priority**, not the older **GCM high-priority**.  Or maybe that is what you meant to be recommending, in which case disregard this comment.